# How to combine variables with strings in a formula with vba

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm struggling with writing the correct grammar of a formula using the property "xlA1", I want to use the next formula:  IF(X311=0," ",X311), I want to change "311" of the X for a variable, but I don't know how to write it, I tried this:

```
inputFormula = "=IF("X" & a "& "=0," "," & "X" & a &")"
```

but I get an error.

Thanks for your help!.

Comment: `"=IF(X" & a & "=0,"" "",X" & a & ")"`

Comment: Thanks!!! I saw where my mistake was , have a nice day!.